# Find the intersection point between these two equations

Tags: polynomials, factoring

We have
$$ f(x) = 12\sqrt x $$
and
$$ g(x) = x^2 - 7x + 12 $$

I need to find where they intersect.
So far I've reduced the expression to
$$
12\sqrt x = x^2 - 7x + 12
$$
$$
12 \sqrt x = (x-4)(x-3)
$$
Square both sides and we get
$$
144x = (x-4)^2(x-3)^2
$$

Using a graph tools I get this visual and the points 0.51839, 9.62145 as a solution.
But how do I get to these values myself?

[image]

Comment: There are no particularly nice closed forms for the roots of this equation, as it happens. You could use Newton's method or something similar to approximate the roots to the desired accuracy (that's what the graphing tool is doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $\sqrt{x}=t$, the equation converts to
$$12t=t^4-7t^2+12$$
$$or \ t^4-7t^2-12t+12=0$$
Now this is what we call a depressed quartic equation and we can use method developed by Rene Descartes to solve such equations

let us say
$$t^4-7t^2-12t+12=(t^2+at+b)(t^2+ct+d)=0$$
Then by expanding and comparing coefficients we have
$$a+c=0, \ d+b+ac=-7$$
$$ad+bc = -12,\ bd = 12$$

We will have to use the cubic formula and we can solve for $a, b, c, d$ as
$$a= -c=3.821844$$
$$b=5.373168,\ d=2.233322$$

And finally we can separately solve for $t^2+at+b=0$ and $t^2+ct+d=0$ using calculated values of $a, b, c, d$.
The first one gives complex roots but for $t^2+ct+d=0$ putting $c=-3.821844$ and $d=2.233322$ we obtain two real roots as $t=3.10185$ and $0.719998$

Thus using $x=t^2$ we find $x$ to be equal to $0.518397$ and $9.621473$. 
That's it.

**EDIT**: There is also a quartic formula for solving degree $4$ polynomials but just by looking at its form, it becomes obvious as why is it not very popular. For more info regarding quartic formula you may refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation

Comment: Why 10t in the beginning and not 12t? But great explanation. I will read up on Descartes.

Comment: Yes you are right, it should be 12 only. I will correct it. Thanks.

Comment: @MRaymaker this might also be helpful https://youtu.be/cUzklzVXJwo

Comment: Great video, thanks. It helped a lot understanding the concepts.